# Transparent overlay on responsive square grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make responsive square image grids each consisting of 9 images.

I just used simple bootstrap grid layout to make the grids -

```
div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="home_images" src="#image*" style="height:25%; width:27%">
    <!--Nine more images like this-->
</div>
```

I needed to add an overlay gray low opacity square on top of (absolute positioning) each of the square grids to add h2 text on the center of each grid. How do I go ahead with it as the grids don't have a specific height?

[image]

Comment: There are **hundreds** of questions about overlays on images on SO. Try doing a search first.

Comment: Overlaying is not my problem, my problem is getting the height of the overlay div. How do I overlay when each of col-md-4 don't have a specified height? I couldn't get a similar responsive div problem on search.

Comment: can you provide your html css and js codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .grid {
      width: 80%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid red;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .row {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .item {
      width: 30%;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    .grid:after {
      content: "Heading Two Title"; /*allow to show up*/
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; /*cover grid area*/
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0; /*make it stay on the grid*/
      background-color: #a0a0a0; /*instead of opacity choose a light gray color*/
      z-index: -1; /*place behind so as not to cover the grid elements*/
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 3em; /*make as big as needed*/
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /grid -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That was not what I wanted but it definitely helped me in the right direction. Thanks for the answer